# Dependence of melting/boiling on external electric or magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition

$H_2O$ is a rather strongly polarized molecule ($\epsilon_r\approx 80$) and it is also diamagnetic ($\chi_m \approx -9\cdot 10^{-6}$). My question is how does the melting or boiling  $p-T$ curve change in external electric and/or magnetic fields?